# qualtrics JavaScript to programmatically skip to end of block

Tags: javascript, dom-events, qualtrics

I need to write a JavaScript in a Qualtrics survey to skip to the end of the block when a custom button is clicked.  I have added the button using the HTML in a particular section of the block and want to move to the end of the block when it is clicked.

I am not sure how to handle this.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the jsfiddle will be explanatory enough, but I'll go on some after I've dropped the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nYxFg/38/).

What I'm using there is what's called a named anchor, which is an octothorpe appended to a url (after querystring by the way), which tells the browser where to go on page, but unlike most URL loads, it doesn't reload the page (as demonstrated with the `alert`.) That said, I haven't tested the solution with a querystring in the URL, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.